# Git: Add untracked files form origin

Tags: git

My server code allows for image uploading, and populates the `/images` directory in `origin` with uploaded content.

My working directory, `master`, obviously does not have these files and does not track these files. I'd like to pull the newly added images on my server to my local repo. Is this possible? If so, how?

**Origin**

```
/app
  /images
    upload_1.jpg // untracked
    upload_2.jpg // untracked
    upload_3.jpg // untracked
  file_upload.php
```

**Master (local)**

```
/app
  /images
  file_upload.php
```

I *really* need help here guys. Is there anyone who can answer this for me?

Rephrasing this, I have untracked files added dynamically to my remote repo. I need to somehow get them onto my local working directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pull files until they're committed. You could possibly make a script that automatically commits them (maybe to a temporary branch) when a user uploads images?

Answer (score 0):

origin is not a directory. It is the name of a remote that a git repo is configured for. If you have a repo where origin points to from your machine and that has a working folder with an images directory, then you will have to include in your process the act of adding and committing these:

```
git add -A && git commit -m "more images"
```

Now you can fetch from origin and get those images. update your local branch by fast-forward merging or resetting to the remote tracking branch. You can pull to combine fetch and merge.

Comment: but that would only add the files on my local working directory, right?

Comment: How would I add the untracked files that are already on my remote server?

Comment: no, this would be on the remote, non-bare repo. The untracked files would be added by the commands I posted.